# Abaqus: define an analytical field in terms of R = f(Th)

Tags: abaqus

I know that by default, the analytical fields are of the form Z = f(X,Y), where we only get to input f(X,Y). However, I have a problem in cylindrical coordinates, where I need to input an expression of the form R = f(Th). How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a similar fashion by selecting an appropriate coordinate system. From the manual:

> The parameter names that are available depend on the type of coordinate system that you select: (...) Cylindrical: **R**, **Th**, and **Z** are the values on the R-, -, and Z-axes, respectively